# How to determine the source of CSS line?

Tags: html, css, display

I have a question about how content-hiding feature is implemented on **thefreedictionary.com** site.
I don't understand how does it work.

If you visit the following URL **with AdBlock enabled**,
http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/stack+overflow
the main content will be hidden.

Even if JavaScript is disabled (I'm using "NoScript" FireFox add-on), the main content will still be hidden.

Let's look at the main content div:

```
<div id="content" class="yt">
```

The path to this div is the following (the image is clickable):

[image: where main div is located]

Please note that the class name (`yt` in my case) is different on every page refresh, so your class name may contain another 2 letters.

By looking at "Rules" and "Computed" tabs in Firefox Developer Tools we can see that `.yt` class has its `display` attribute set to `none`.

[image: display is overridden to none]

It is easy to check that it is this checkbox that controls the visibility of main content.

[image: the checkbox]

My question is:  **Where does this css line come from?**

It looks like a css data URI, but I can't find data URIs in html file.
The html file refers to "all.css" which also does not contain setting `.yt` `display` to `none`.
JavaScript is disabled, so `display` property could not be changed dynamically by a script.

I'm interesting, what trick is being used here.
Could someone explain please?

Comment: Hmm, I visited the link with AdBlock Plus enabled in Chrome and Firefox and nothing was hidden from me.

Comment: You should be able to click the little "css,.yt..." line beside the rule and it will show you were on the page that is defined. But I have adblock in chrome and nothing's hidden either.

Comment: @MichaelCoker The `css,.yt` link points to an inline style that's actually in the page source but does not include any `none` display, only `.yt{margin:0 0 13px 0;display:block;overflow:hidden;width:100%}`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Sorry, I'm wrong. It just takes you to the CSS panel in developer tools and shows the last open stylesheet. It must be a bug in developer tools.

Comment: The only trick I can figure out is a CSS transition but I can't find it, it's too late and I should be with my family :)